# Button declared in Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, button

I am trying to develop a shopping cart and i am stuck with the following issue. i am creating a new product dynamically using jQuery. The following piece of code adds new product to the cart:

```
        var productAdded = $('<tr class="product" data-id_modal="'+ id +'"><td class="product_name2"><button href="#0" class="button2" id="'+ id +'">' + product_name + '</button></td><td class="quantity"><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-'+ id +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></span></td><td class="price">' + product_price + '</td><td><a href="#0" class="delete-item"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td></tr>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
```

As you can see above i am creating a new 'button' within javascript. For that element click event is not firing.

```
$(".button2").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $("#add_product_comment").dialog({
                      buttons : {
                          "Άκυρο" : function() {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        "Αποθήκευση" : function() {
                          setInterval(function(){}, 1000); 
                          $( "#add_product_comment" ).dialog( "close" );
                          // $('#two').load(document.URL +  ' #two'); using ajax reload div                           
                        }
                      }
                    });

                    $("#add_product_comment").dialog("open");
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', '#000000');

                  });
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on click instead.

```
$(document).on('click','.button2',function(){
    //your action.
});
```

Comment: this event is wrapped with in the document ready function.

Comment: That's not the problem.Try this.

Comment: ok give me 2mins.. thanks friend

Comment: If there is any problem tell me.

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ..button2

Comment: There is two `..` marks before the button change it.

Comment: :) i saw it and changed it but still i get no response...

Comment: I think you are getting error because of other problems. Could you share your code on jsbin or jsfiddle??

Comment: Yes i will bro , later thank you very much for your support

Comment: Refer this [link]http://jsbin.com/mitecogusu/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you for the solution. it worked. but i do not understand the reason. what is the difference between the two event triggers? $(document).on('click','.button2',function(){                                                     //$(".button2").click(function(e) {

Comment: Dear Sarath, just one more question in case you might be able to help out. For each new row append to the cart i add a modal just as you stated in your code. For each modal i append a form for adding a comment onto each record(tr). however when i set the value to a single row using an input field this value is automatically asigned to all rows listed in the cart. Any idea on this? Thanks !!

Comment: yeah it'll change for all the row because modal is common for all. but the comment is different. So when ever the customer enters comment you can just save it in  data [attribute] and data base. When he clicking the product again fetch the comment from data or database using ajax.

Comment: check this http://jsbin.com/fisuluwewo/edit?js,output

Comment: The inner button "iphone" does not work for each.

Comment: You mean modal title ?? I couldn't understand.

Comment: According to your example When i add a new row then.i try to click on "iphone" button but nothing hapens.  I think is because i viewing from my handset. I will try it tommrow on my pc. Thanks friend

Comment: try it in your pc. Reply back.

Comment: You are my guru :) Thank you v much Sarath!!!!!!!